# How to rename all files in a directory adding prefix of current unix date

Tags: linux, bash, date, rename

I use the following command to rename all files with no spaces adding prefix "Hello"

```
for FILENAME in *; do mv $FILENAME Hello_$FILENAME; done
```

I use the following command to get unix datestamp

```
date +%s
```

How do I replace `Hello` with `date +%s` output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you could use the `$(date +%s)` [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) syntax to get the command output (and I suggest quotes) like

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(date +%s)_$i"; done
```

Comment: How would I reverse out the change and remove the date? Let's say the date is 1415856823

Comment: @Andy I think you could use `for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(echo ${i} | cut -f2 -d'_')"; done`. Also, if your question is answered please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/243725).

Comment: @Andy I tried it here first. Are you sure you got all of that? The `done` is on the second line.

Comment: Pardon, problem is between chair and keyboard. It works great.

Comment: how would I use your proposed solution with absolute path? If i launch the command from another directory it seems to make the $i variable a complete path instead of just the filename.